# Mariadb index creation on large table leads to corruption

Tags: index, mariadb, corruption

I am trying to create an index for a very large table called `reception_edges_denorm` (200GB) in MariaDB. The table has 4,916,267,670 rows and the following schema :

1. src_trs_id: bigint(20)
2. src_trs_start: int(11)
3. src_trs_end: int(11)
4. dst_trs_id: bigint(20)
5. dst_trs_start: int(11)
6. dst_trs_end: int(11)

In the MariaDB command line I attempt to create the index using

```
SET SESSION aria_sort_buffer_size = 64424509440; -- 60GB
SET SESSION aria_repair_threads = 8; -- when sorting
CREATE INDEX src_trs ON reception_edges_denorm(src_trs_id);
```

The server VM has 77GB of RAM and 16 cores so I assumed the larger buffer sizes would help in speeding up the index creation. The first phase of `copying a tmp table` finished successfully and the second stage `Repair by sorting` goes up to 50% and then doesn't show any progress. After a day I receive the output `Query OK, 4937767670 rows affected (10 hours 33 min 33.591 sec) Records: 4937767670  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0`. The first red flag is that the number of rows is different from the number of data rows that should be there. Moreover, when I attempt to use the table and index it is not returning correct query results. Upon running `CHECK TABLE reception_edges_denorm` I get the following messages  `Key in wrong position at page 77815808` and `Table corrupt`.
At this stage I restart the docker container hoping to fix any issues. However, after restarting even a simple `SELECT` query return the message : `Table is crashed and last repair failed"' for './hpc@002dhd/reception_edges_denorm'` . The issue seems to only be with this large table as I am able to create several other indices on smaller tables (12-13GB in size) and run queries on them fine.

I am unsure why this is happening. The same corruption happened a second time even after I destroyed the server and cloud storage VM and loaded the data in fresh and attempted to create the same index. In the previous run I attempted to repair the table using `aria_chk` which failed after a day.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try the indexing with only 1GB for aria_sort_buffer_size.  I would expect it to resort to a disk-based "sort-merge", which might be almost as fast.  And hopefully less error-prone.l

Comment: Is there some reason for using Aria instead of InnoDB?

Comment: What are the trs_start/end values?  If IP addresses, they need to be `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: What does value does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reception_edges_denorm` give you?

Comment: I have once more recreated the database this time only with the table in question. There is 444GB free on disk and the table occupies 198GB at the moment. @RickJames I will try to create the index with a smaller aria_sort_buffer_size and check if it works. The trs_start/end_values are array offsets and indeed should be UNSIGNED. I load the data from Spark so I think I might need to change the schema to all be UNSIGNED INT which might take up lesser space as well.
The `SELECT COUNT(*)` prior to index creation returns `4916267670` the correct number of rows.

Comment: Also @RickJames we had other databases which used the Aria engine hence my choice to go with it over InnoDB

Comment: If things continue to fail, file a bug report with jira.mariadb.com